# Best data structure to store peculiarly structured data

Tags: java, data-structures

So, I'll be looping through a data base and there will be a bunch of campaigns. Each campaign will have some demos and some sites where certain conditions are satisfied. I want to plot some graphs for the data corresponding to all the campaigns, sites and demos. I was thinking of using java, first getting the campaign, site and demo combinations where the conditions are satisfied and then looping through all of them, running individual queries based on their values and plotting the graphs using maybe, GNU plot. My questions are -

1. Is there a better way to achieve this (with minimal queries).
2. If I do do it this way, I first have to store the information.

I was thinking of storing the campaign ids in an ArrayList of Integers, the demos for each campaign in

```
  ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>
```

and the sites for each campaign in

```
  ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>
```

Is there a more efficient way of storing this information?

Comment: Are you storing the data just for the purpose of making a chart, or are you wanting to save it longer term as well? For charting purposes, your choice might be driven by whatever charting mechanism/library you choose. If you want web based, for example, there's Google Charts (https://developers.google.com/chart/), etc.

Comment: I personally would send one query per chart to the database, each delivering the data in a structure as closely as possible to the structure needed for the chart. This would require less code, as SQL is declarative and has no need to run nested loops etc. And databases are designed to do huge data processing. But your mileage may vary, especially if yo have few SQL experience.

Comment: I don't need to store the data for later, just want the plots. Also, there are going to be a whole bunch of them and I'm looking to save all of them as files. GNU plot seems like a good option for doing this, but other ideas like the Google charts will be great. @Frank: My current solution is some thing along sending one query for each combination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend creating a new class to hold your campaign data and storing references to each object within an ArrayList if you need to keep a handle to them in memory (may not be necessary).

From a purist point of view, the class should be backed by a Data Access Object (DAO) and Plain Old Java Object (POJO) to manage database access and storage in memory but if this is a simple prototype then I wouldn't worry too much. I'd also recommend a utility class to convert/write your chart data - all accessible from your Campaign class.

The  Campaign class should also be able to work out whether your conditions are satisfied - and if it's worth generating those charts.